# search not works in "phpbb3" forum

Tags: search, phpbb3

I'm trying find reason of non-working search in my phpbb3 forum.
It works for different situation. but if i'm trying find word which exists in [code] tag it does not returns any results.

Comment: Please provide us some element about your config files and your strategy (Full Text Native search, Mysql Full text search...).

Comment: Hi. Sorry for late answer. Probably i have missed your reply. 
I leaved here my configuration:

https://www.phpbb.com/community/viewtopic.php?f=466&t=2415646&p=14706366#p14706366

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> It is normal not to find text in code tags Read
>   [this](http://[enter%20link%20description%20here][1]%20%20strong%20text%20%20%20[1]:%20https://www.phpbb.com/community/viewtopic.php?p=14706801&sid=317239ac5d106db3e2a5a2b89b785598#p14706801)

As I understand, phpbb does not index words in tags as [code] and probably in other tags. 
Later I will try find it in source